# Neo4j Import tool error in RC01

Tags: import, neo4j

I've successfully imported a large Neo4j database on 2.2M03 using the batch import tool. 
But now I need to use 2.2RC01 and cannot use the same import tool where I get a Import null error when I use the identical files I've used for the previous import.

The message.log reads:

```
2015-03-14 08:36:19.670+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Import starting
2015-03-14 08:36:19.732+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Creating new db @ C:\neo4j\neo4j\data\test.db\neostore
2015-03-14 08:36:20.418+0000 INFO  [org.neo4j]: Missing counts store, rebuilding it.
2015-03-14 08:37:10.132+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Error during import null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.input.csv.InputGroupsDeserializer.position(InputGroupsDeserializer.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IteratorBatcherStep.position(IteratorBatcherStep.java:70)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.IoProducerStep.stat(IoProducerStep.java:52)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.stats.StepStats.stat(StepStats.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.stats.StepStats.toString(StepStats.java:115)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.SpectrumExecutionMonitor.printSpectrum(SpectrumExecutionMonitor.java:138)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.SpectrumExecutionMonitor.check(SpectrumExecutionMonitor.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.MultiExecutionMonitor.check(MultiExecutionMonitor.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisors.superviseDynamicExecution(ExecutionSupervisors.java:65)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:226)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:151)
    at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:263)
```

Something weird is that at one point, the import failed after importing n number of nodes and the other after importing a different number of nodes.

Is there a change in the format of files in 2.2RC01? I've read the manual but didn't spot any difference.

Comment: Can you share your files with us? You can also email me via michael at neo4j.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed and will be included in the next release of 2.2. For your reference: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/4128